# Checking if numbers are valid from inputs then adding them

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure there's a way to do this but what's happening is that I am adding 2 values from inputs then displaying them in a label `$totalRetailAmountField`. However, sometimes if you put dashes in either of the numbers, it's throwing off the final number (even when using a regex to strip out dashes, commas, etc). Is there a way to first check the numbers, then add them if they are? Thanks

```
function calcTotalRetailVal() {
    var num1 = $oneTimeCostField.val();
    var num2 = $recurringTotalCostField.val();
    var result = parseFloat(num1.replace(/(,|[^\d.-]+)+/g, '')) + parseFloat(num2.replace(/(,|[^\d.-]+)+/g, ''));

    if (!isNaN(result)) {
        $totalRetailAmountField.text('$' + result.toFixed(2));
    }
}
calcTotalRetailVal();
$oneTimeCostField.on("keydown keyup", function() {
    calcTotalRetailVal();
});
$recurringTotalCostField.on("keydown keyup", function() {
    calcTotalRetailVal();
});
```

Comment: Use `<input type="number">`?

Comment: thanks, these are PHP forms that are dynamically generated so the handling of that has to be in the JS.

Comment: Provide some sample input that fails in a runnable [mcve]. Click on `<>` in question editor and can run it right in the page here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern `(,|[^\d.-]+)+` you use an alternation to match either a comma, or a negated character class that match any character that is NOT listed due to using the `^` at the start like `[^\d.-]`

That means you are not removing digits, dots but you are also not removing dashes.

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/m1eEDb/1)

Depending on what you want to replace with an empty string, you could use a single character class and list what you would like to replace like  matching a comma, dash or whitespace char `[,\s-]`, or use `\D+` to match all non digits.

For example `num1.replace(/[,\s-]+/g, '')` or `num1.replace(/\D+/g, '')`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood the question right but if your intent is to get rid of all possible dashes in a string, using the following regExp as the first parameter of your replace method should be fine I suppose.

```
/-/g
```

So your code would go from

```
var result = parseFloat(num1.replace(/(,|[^\d.-]+)+/g, '')) + parseFloat(num2.replace(/(,|[^\d.-]+)+/g, ''));
```

to

```
var result = parseFloat(num1.replace(/-/g, '')) + parseFloat(num2.replace(/-/g, ''));
```

In fact the regExp you're using does match anything that's **not** a digit, the . character or a dash.

Comment: Thanks, that works fairly well however it's still adding the 2 fields wrong if you throw a "-" or some odd character in it (before it gets stripped)

Comment: Can you provide an example? Or a few examples? :)

Comment: Hi Gustavo, thanks. It was due to the keyup event - i had to make it a change event.